# c# Crystall report : The data source object is invalid

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I'am using an Class Object as a DataSource of my Crystal reports : 
[image]

and i'am using the Crystal report Viewer  :

```
    Printer.Lavage.Report.LavageReport Report = new Printer.Lavage.Report.LavageReport();
    Report.SetDataSource(order);

    Printer.Lavage.View.LavageReport_FRM LavageReporter = new Printer.Lavage.View.LavageReport_FRM();
    LavageReporter.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Report;
    LavageReporter.Show();
```

but i'am gettings the exception :

```
The data source object is invalid.
```

Answer (score 6):

The Data Source of the Report Must be a List of that Object it works after changing that in code :

Replace `Report.SetDataSource(order);`
to `Report.SetDataSource(new[] { order });`